# 2d Brownian motion hitting a point

Tags: stochastic-processes, percolation

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb C$ be a simply connected domain, $\tau = \exp(2\pi\mathrm i/3)$ and $a(\alpha),a(\tau\alpha),a(\tau^2\alpha)$ are some accessible points of $\Omega$.

In [this paper](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~mlyubich/Archive/SLE/percol.pdf) by S. Smirnov he writes (Section 2, p.4, after equation $(2)$):

> `[...]` is also given by the probability that Brownian motion started at $z$ and reflected on the arcs $a(\alpha)a(\tau\alpha)$ and $a(\tau^2\alpha)a(\alpha)$ at $\frac{\pi}{3}$ angle pointing towards $a(\alpha)$ hits `[the point]` $a(\alpha)$ before the `[opposite]` arc $a(\tau\alpha)a(\tau^2\alpha)$.

I wonder if for such reflected Brownian motion the probability of eventually hitting the predefined point $a(\alpha)$ is non-zero since for usual Brownian motion on the plane it is zero for any point.

I am also confused in which sense the reflection with an angle $\pi/3$ towards $a(\alpha)$ is defined.